# How to copy an object in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-webpages

I have to do a duplicate button using c# in asp.net web pages and it tears me up because I found some documentation from Microsoft's website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-write-a-copy-constructor,  but somehow still don't know how to make it works in my project. I tried to write a copy constructor in my Models project where I have my class and properties:

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        //Instance constructor.
        public Person()
        {
        }
        //Copy constructor.
        public Person(Person previousPerson)
        {
            Name = previousPerson.Name;
            Age = previousPerson.Age;
        }
}
```

and then I have my content page where I want to show a form :

```
@using ClassLibrary1
@{

    if (IsPost)
    {
        Person person = new Person();


        if (Validation.IsValid())
        {
            switch (Request.Form["action"])
            {
                case "Submit":
                    person.Name = Request.Form["Name"];
                    person.Age = Request.Form["Age"].AsInt();
                    break;
                case "Duplicate":
                    Person person1 = new Person(person);
                    person1.Name = Request.Form["Name"];
                    person1.Age = Request.Form["Age"].AsInt();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
<form method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Add Customer</legend>
        <div>
            <label for="Name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Name"
                   value="@Request.Form["Name"]" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="Age"> Age:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Age"
                   value="@Request.Form["Age"]" />
        </div>
        <button name="action" value="Save" type="submit">Save</button>
        <button name="action" value="Duplicate" type="submit">Duplicate</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I want to let the user complete the `form` and when they press the Save button the `form` will be submitted.
My problem is when I want to duplicate the form and make a deep copy of that `form`.
I missing something and I don' know what. Any idea?
By the way. I wish you a great day.

Comment: Why do you need a "deep copy of form"?

Comment: You are duplicating the Person object, not the form. A form is a HTML entity, not a C# object, so you have to use some form of DOM manipulation

Comment: Well you are always creating the `person` instance new with `Person person = new Person();` so you are losing the previous entered data. And even if you did keep the `person` instance alive you are overwriting the information anyway with the lines `person1.Name = Request.Form["Name"]; person1.Age = Request.Form["Age"].AsInt();`